# Local host takes long time to load

Tags: performance, xampp, localhost

Got a website pretty heavy on images and sql calls, and when I access it on my localhost, pages take up to 30 sec to load which is pretty annoying. I'm using xampp. Is it possible to figure out why exactly it is so slow and how to speed it up?

Comment: is it possible to include some code so we know what we are getting into?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with SQL being very slow. Instead of using "localhost" for connecting to my local database, I changed it to 127.0.0.1. It has something to do with domain name lookup. Went from 30-ish seconds to miliseconds.